# How to output when I use wp_handle_upload_prefilter, Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Simple request, how can I find what I got in $file ? (array ?)

When I add print_r or echo, Wordpress only show me an error messeage.

I googled, but I found nothing, because my poor english maybe.

```
function wp_modify_uploaded_file_names($file) {
    $info = pathinfo($file['name']);
    $ext  = empty($info['extension']) ? '' : '.' . $info['extension'];
    $name = basename($file['name'], $ext);

    $file['name'] = uniqid() . $ext; // uniqid method

    print_r($file);

   return $file;
}

add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'wp_modify_uploaded_file_names', 1, 1);
```

Comment: I am using php function event_log. it works fairly enough.

Answer (score 2):

Typically on filters, you can't properly output by print_r or echo...or even var_dump() in most cases.  You can do it if you want, but the output will end up somewhere else than where you expect it to be.

What I usually do is use var_export() and set 'return' to true and include it in the return statement of my filter.

However, in the case of wp_handle_upload_prefilter() if you include something other than a properly formatted $file variable in the return statement, you'll get the error that you saw.

To see how $file is formatted and used, I'd just look in the WP core (specifically /wp-admin/includes/file.php ).